# find match and remove them leaving only what is not a match

Tags: sed

I have a file with following. 
And i want to use sed and regex to solve it .

```
Alex Trump, New York, 123445-4567
Jimmy Carter, Los Santos, 123245-3x20
Alec Baldwin, babylon 5,
Luke Skywater, cloud city, 223345-1420
```

So when i run it removes all matched line and leave Jimmy and Alec or write what was not found to new file.

If i use regex i know that the code below will look for matching digit

```
\d\d\d\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d$
```

I want something like this. 
cat file | sed -r \d\d\d\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d$
So when i run it, it removes all matched line and leave Jimmy and Alec or write what was not found to new file.

Comment: Use `sed -E '/[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}$/d' file > newfile`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/1UwcxW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -E '/[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}/d' file > newfile
```

See [this `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/97y2qt).

**Details**

- `-E` - POSIX ERE flag, no need to escape `{` and `}` in quantifiers
- `[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}` - regex matching 6 digits, `-` and then 4 digits
- `d` - removes the lines that matched the regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks, at first i thought it did not work, had to remove $ so it could remove all matches.